# Set value of excluded field in django ModelForm programmatically

Tags: python, django

I have a `ModelForm` class where I want to exclude one of the fields (`language`) from the form and add it programmatically. I tried to add the language in the clean method, but got an `IntegrityError` (`"Column 'language_id' cannot be null"`). I assume this is because any data for `language` returned from `clean()` will be ignored since it's in the exclude tuple. I'm using the form in a `ModelAdmin` class. I haven't managed to find any way to deal with this, so any tips or hints will be much appreciated.

```
from django import forms
from myapp import models
from django.contrib import admin


class DefaultLanguagePageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(DefaultLanguagePageForm, self).clean()
        english = models.Language.objects.get(code="en")
        cleaned_data['language'] = english

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = models.Page
        exclude = ("language",)

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DefaultLanguagePageForm
```

Answer (score 10):

What you can do is when you save the form in the view, you don't commit the data. You can then set the value of the excluded field programmatically. I run into this a lot when I have a user field and I want to exclude that field and set to the current user.

```
form = form.save(commit=False)
form.language = "en"
form.save()
```

Here's a little more info on the commit=False --> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: I'm not calling the form explicitly since I'm using it for a ModelAdmin class. But maybe there's some hook I can use on the ModelAdmin. I'll look into it when I'm at my computer again.

Comment: It seems like I'll be able to use ModelAdmin.save_model(request, obj, form, change) (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model), so I guess I won't actually need to access the form instance. Thanks for the tip though, I'll most likely find the use for commit=False another time.

Comment: @JoarLeth, if you have determined a solution then it would be helpful if you reported it as answer and accepted your answer.

Comment: is there a way to do this for `django.forms.ModelForm`??

Comment: @SrinathGanesh have a look to this alternative approach: you do not exclude the field you want to _hide_ and overwrite it with a custom _hidden_ widget as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893460/1636885). I had to use it and it worked!