# How to exclude django form field from render but still keep it for validation?

Tags: django, forms

If I have a model (extract):

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=64, null=True, upload_to="couponimages")
```

And a form (extract):

```
class InsertCoupon(forms.ModelForm):
    image=forms.ImageField(
        required=False, #note explicitly declared false
        max_length=64,
        widget=forms.FileInput() 
        )
    class Meta:
        model=Coupon,
        exclude = ("image",)
```

Then I notice that the image field is still rendered when I do `{{ form.as_table }}`. If I remove the explicit declaration of the field from the form class, then it doesn't render, but I don't get the benefit of form validation and easy modelform insertion to the database. I want to use my own widget for this field (`FileInput` is ugly) - do I have to hence code all the html myself, or is there a way to use `as_table`?

Comment: Well, don't use form.as_table then.

Comment: So no way to render the table and exclude a field from rendering but not from the form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So a better way to exclude just a single field in the template might be:

```
<table>
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field != "image" %}
    <tr><td>{{ field }}</td></tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Beats manually writing out all the fields.

Comment: Don't forget to call the name when checking this. {% if field.name != "image" %}

Answer (score 7):

I think the best way to achieve that is to create a widget that renders nothing:

```
class NoInput(forms.Widget):
    input_type = "hidden"
    template_name = ""

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        return ""

class YourForm(forms.Form):
    control = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=NoInput)
```

This way you can still use {{form}} in your template.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do what you want to do here is write a custom widget to display the file field differently.  However, the best way to answer the exact question you asked, without having to render the form manually in the templates, is to overwrite the as_table method of the form:

```
class InsertCoupon(forms.ModelForm):

    def as_table(self, *args, **kwargs):
        del self.fields['image']
        return super(InsertCoupon, self).as_table(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render form manualy like this:

in `views.py`

```
return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

in `template.html`

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.field1 }}
    {{ form.field2 }}
          .
          .
          .
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

also take a look to [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/forms/).