# Accessing excluded fields in Django form's clean method

Tags: django, forms

Imagine we have a Django ORM model, let's call it `MyModel`, and it's respective form, let's call it `MyForm`. Also, let's imagine that there's a field in `MyModel` which has been excluded from `MyForm`. Let's call this field `excluded_field`. The question is, how do we tackle the situation when we have to use `excluded_field` during the validation of the form (meaning, the form's `clean` method)?
I like encapsulating user input validation and corresponding customized error messages in form's `clean` and `field_name_clean` method as suggested by doc, because moving all business logic to forms makes my views elegant and simple and the entire code DRY.

Just to be specific, consider the following code:

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
        # ...some fields
        excluded_field = models.CharField()
        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'my_model'
```

And the respective form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

   def clean(self):
        # how do I access excluded_field here ?
```

One might ask why I exclude this field from the form ? Well, it's because this field's value is generated programmatically, and the user does not - and should not - know anything about its value.

So, **the question is**, can we access excluded fields in form's `clean` method if we need it for user input validation, or for such cases, we have to organize user input validation in views by using the model instance instead of form?

Comment: you have excluded the field from the from, but it is still in the model. Did you try to access it via instance? Something like in clean(self) - self.instance.excluded_field?

Comment: Don't exclude the field, just do not display it and add it to the form before the validation (copy request.POST and add the field programmatically).

Comment: Or display it as a hidden field and override it's value in backend, if you don't want to mess with your template code.

Comment: You can achieve what @cdvv7788 suggested by following this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893460/1636885