# Hide a field form in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to hide the 'password' field in my edit profile form. Even though I have excluded the field it still appears, here is my forms.py file:

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = (
        'email',
        'first_name',
        'last_name'
    )
    exclude = (
        'password',
    )
```

Here is my html:

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

A screenshot of what is currently being produced

[image]

To clarify, I am trying to completely hide the password field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude django form field from render but still keep it for validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385421/how-to-exclude-django-form-field-from-render-but-still-keep-it-for-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you inherited from [UserChangeForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1b49b792e9f0e6a5ae22f49f75586847e7e183bf/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L126). Unfortunately, your `Meta` only affects fields that are created from the model by django, not the fields that are defined there manually (which is by the way a bit different behaviour than DRF serializers).

For your case, all you need to do is:

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = None
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name'
        )
```

Or create your own `UserChangeForm` from the very beginning.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = (
          'email',
          'first_name',
          'last_name'
       )
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['password'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Hope it help for your problem